# Redis CLI disconnects immediately when setting a key in Azure Redis Cache

Tags: azure, redis

I provisioned an Azure Redis Cache, under the Basic 250MB tier, with TLS version set to `Default`. I used the Redis CLI from Windows 10 version 2004. I also attempted to use Redis CLI from a Multipass Ubuntu Linux VM, and got the same result.

I run the following command to get an interactive Redis CLI prompt, which is painfully slow at around 10 seconds:

```
redis-cli -h mytestcache658.redis.cache.windows.net -p 6380 -a 'REDACTEDREDACTED'
```

Then I run a simple Redis command from the interactive CLI:

```
mytestcache658.redis.cache.windows.net:6380> SET FirstName Trevor
```

As soon as I run this command, I immediately am disconnected from the Azure Redis Cache.

On Windows 10, Redis CLI version `3.2.100`, I receive this error:

```
Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

On Ubuntu Linux with Redis CLI version `5.0.7`, I receive this error:

```
Error: Connection reset by peer
```

**Question**: How exactly do I use Azure Redis Cache? It doesn't appear to be working at all.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the version of Redis that's running in Azure is an older version (4.0). Redis doesn't support TLS until version 6.0, as an optional feature, according to [their documentation](https://redis.io/topics/encryption). Of course, nothing in the Azure Portal actually tells you this.

Eventually, after conferring with several colleagues, I came across a [broken link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/287c659d-98f0-4e86-bf4c-b5433603d5c2/how-to-connect-azureredis-from-rediscli) to a [6 year-old blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/announcing-asp-net-session-state-provider-for-redis-preview-release.aspx) on an unrelated topic, which allegedly covers using `stunnel` to establish a TLS connection first.

After searching Google for `stunnel azure redis`, I found a link to some documentation that describes two methods of connecting to Azure Redis:

1. Disable TLS (not recommended, for obvious reasons)
2. Use [stunnel to establish a TLS connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-redis-cli-tool)

I chose to install `stunnel` on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) instead of using the Windows version of `stunnel`.

```
sudo apt-get install stunnel
```

Then, I created a configuration file that points `stunnel` to my Azure Redis Cache.

```
foreground = yes

[redis-cli]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:6380
connect = mytestcache658.redis.cache.windows.net:6380
```

Then I simply run `stunnel` in the foreground, using a separate tmux pane, referencing the configuration file.

```
stunnel stunnel.conf
```

In another tmux pane, I run `redis-cli` and connect to the remote Azure Redis Cache. You can either specify the primary key / password using the `-a` parameter, or you can connect anonymously and then use the `auth REDACTED` command in `redis-cli` to authenticate.

```
redis-cli -p 6380 -a REDACTEDREDACTED
```

or

```
redis-cli -p 6380
redis> AUTH REDACTED
```